# Gradle test failed to find flowId on teamcity

Tags: java, gradle, teamcity-9.0

We are using Teamcity 9.0.3 and we try to run gradle build with tests. But, it failed with the following exception:

```
[15:25:41][:test] Failed to find flowId for [com.stub.AppTest]
[15:25:41][:test] java.lang.NullPointerException: Failed to find flowId for [com.stub.AppTest]
[15:25:41][:test]   at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
[15:25:41][:test]   at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
[15:25:41][:test]   at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
[15:25:41][:test]   at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:422)
```

I use gradle wrapper and 2.5 version of it and teamcity agents for build.
How can I fix this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Well, i found answer: it is a bug of this version.

https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/TW-42012

For fix it you may to update version to 9.0.4 or later.

Comment: Thanks for sharing your answer (i had the same problem ;) )